# Configuring a shared library

Tags: linux

I have downloaded a C++ library to use in my code, and I would like to configure it to be a shared library. The library currently sits in my working directory. I have copied all the shared object (.so) files to /lib64, as well as updated the ld_library_path to point to the library, library_path to point to the library's lib folder, and cplus_include_path to point to the library's include folder. Yet when I include anything from the library in my headers, I get a "no such file or directory" error.

Could someone tell me the additional steps required?

Comment: Are you getting the "no such file or directory" error when trying to `#include` a header associated with the library?  Or when trying to link the final executable against the library itself?

Comment: I assume it's the former because the error points to the location of the include in my header file and my .o file is not produced.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter where the `.so` file is, because you're not using it yet.  What matters is where the headers are.  Have you added any `-I` options in your compile command?

Comment: No I haven't. Do you follow the -I option with the path to the /include folder?